# Making rows of sprites re-appear at top of screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make the rows of sprites reappear at the top of the screen when they disappear off of the bottom.  I'm able to make the sprites move downwards and off the screen but don't know to get them to reappear as soon as one row moves off. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pygame

import sys

from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Rain:

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Rain Drops")

        self.bg_color = (100,100,100)


        self.rain_drops = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_drop()
   

        drop = Drop()



    def run_rain(self):
           

        while True:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        sys.exit()


            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)


            self._update_drops()

            
            self.rain_drops.draw(self.screen)


            pygame.display.flip()


    def _create_drop(self):

        drop = Drop()
        drop.rect.x = -10 
        drop.rect.y = 4
        drop_start_x = drop.rect.x
        drop_start_y = drop.rect.y


        for row_number in range(5):
            for drop_number in range(20):
                drop = Drop()
                drop.rect.x = drop_start_x + 70 * drop_number
                drop.rect.y = drop_start_y + 100 * row_number


                self.rain_drops.add(drop)
    

    def _update_drops(self):
        self.rain_drops.update()



class Drop(Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('smaller_drop.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 1




rain = Rain()
rain.run_rain()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing is best done in your sprite's `.update()` function.  Check to see if the `y` co-ordinate of the sprites `Rect` is past the height of the window, and if-so move it back to the top.

However, you have hard-coded the window dimensions inside the display initialisation function.  We need to know the window length in the update, so these need to be moved out to constant variables.

```
class Rain:
    WINDOW_WIDTH = 1200
    WINDOW_HEIGHT= 800

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.WINDOW_WIDTH, self.WINDOW_HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Rain Drops")
```

Now in the `DropSprite` it's pretty easy to compare the position against the window height.  if the position is greater than the window height,

```
class Drop(Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('smaller_drop.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 1
        # if we go off the bottom of the window, move back to top
        if ( self.rect.y > Rain.WINDOW_HEIGHT ):   
            self.rect.y = 0
```

You may also want the drop to start just above the screen so it "falls" into view.  In this case start it with an `x` of `(0 - self.rect.height)`, since the `x,y` of a rect is the top-left co-ordinate.  Moving it to `0` makes it suddenly appear at the top.  Moving it to `-height` puts it just above the player's view.

Comment: You can actually just get the screen dimensions by asking pygame rather than referring to constants. `screen_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_height()`  You can also use `screen_width = pygame.display.get_surface().get_width()` or get both with `screen_width, screen_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()`. This can be better in case you add window resizing at a later point.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh - Yes, this is a good way to do it if the screen is changing size a lot.  I was trying to keep-style with what the OP had proposed already.  That, and it's easier to both read & type.

Comment: Also when I wrap stuff around the screen I prefer to start them just off the screen and let them move onto the screen, so they do not just teleport fully onto the screen. In this case I would use `if (self.rect.y > Rain.WINDOW_HEIGHT):  self.rect.bottom = 0` rather that setting the `y`.

Comment: i see this makes sense, thank you so very much. just tried it and it works perfectly. i thought as much it would have to do with an If statement but did not know where to place it. so it's not that new sprites are being created and added to the group each time, but rather that the loop keeps running and moving the Y coordinate of the rectangles back to 0 when they cross the window height (800 in this case)?